Request Timeout on API Calls in Production in NextJS App
I have a critial issue on my NextJS app where all of the requests to my API routes time out in production. It used to work perfectly up until recently but now my app is unusable (except for the static landing page). It's working perfectly in my local environment.
I'm using NextJS 14.0.1 with App Router; MongoDB + Mongoose
Here are the timed logs from a simple /api/lead endpoint (create a lead in DB)
// app/api/leads/route.js

import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectMongo from "@/libs/mongoose";
import Lead from "@/models/Lead";

export async function POST(req) {
  console.time("MongoDB Connection");
  await connectMongo();
  console.timeEnd("MongoDB Connection");

  console.time("Request JSON Parsing");
  const body = await req.json();
  console.timeEnd("Request JSON Parsing");

  if (!body.email) {
    return NextResponse.json({ error: "Email is required" }, { status: 400 });
  }

  try {
    console.time("Finding Lead");
    const lead = await Lead.findOne({ email: body.email });
    console.timeEnd("Finding Lead");

    if (!lead) {
      console.time("Creating Lead");
      await Lead.create({ email: body.email });
      console.timeEnd("Creating Lead");
    }

    console.time("Sending Response");
    const response = NextResponse.json({});
    console.timeEnd("Sending Response");
    return response;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Database operation failed", e);
    console.time("Sending Error Response");
    const errorResponse = NextResponse.json(
      { error: e.message },
      { status: 500 }
    );
    console.timeEnd("Sending Error Response");
    return errorResponse;
  }
}



MongoDB Connection: 880.541ms
Request JSON Parsing: 0.913ms
Finding Lead: 556.57ms
Sending Response: 1.31ms

When fetching this through postman, it still takes > 10 seconds for me to receive the response. Default timeout on Netlify / Vercel happens after 10 seconds.
Netlify Logs Screenshot
There are no errors in the browser console, and inspecting the request in the Network tab doesn't help either.
What I did so far:

Checked all recent commits to identify any relevant changes (nothing)
Reset main branch to previous commit and deployed to see if it works (didn't work)
Connecting to production DB from local environment -> Works without issues
Tried using the app through a https ngrok tunnel locally -> Works
Verified that it only affects requests that trigger a database operation
Tried to Deploy both on Vercel and Netlify -> Same issue
Added timed logs to all operations within an endpoint to measure execution time -> see below
Started a new MongoDB cluster and connected to this new instance -> Same issue

Any ideas what could be the problem here? I'm out of ideas.
Edit: Here's an additional timed log

Are you using MongoDB Atlas? If yes, do check the network settings for IP whitelisting. It is possible that MongoDB is rejecting connections coming from Vercel / Netlify Serverless Functions.

Thanks for the tip, but I already set it to accept all connections.

After exploring a lot of possible issues, I managed to solve the error by upgrading all of my dependencies and by removing Posthog. Seems like the library has some issue with one of its dependencies. Not sure why the error only caused the app to crash on production, but well. Hope this saves someone else a few hours in the future.

Hey Philipp, PostHog engineer here - we've a lot of folks using PostHog with NextJS - I'd be amazed and horrified if this is really the issue.
I'd love you to open a support ticket or a GitHub bug with more details about your setup...

Hi, here you go: https://github.com/PostHog/posthog-node/issues/85
Like I said in the issue text, I'm not interested in reintroducing the error into my production environment to pinpoint the exact source, but I hope it helps.
